# label too big for a radiogroup radio button

Tags: extjs

I wish no chario return for a radio button label ... Can someone help me ?

My code is as :

```
 items: [{
            xtype: 'radiogroup',
            margin: "0 0 0 150",
            labelAlign: 'left',
            columns: 2,
            vertical: true,
            items: [
                { boxLabel: 'Standard Communication', name: 'typeOfCommunication', inputValue: '1' },
                { boxLabel: 'Bulk Communication', name: 'typeOfCommunication', inputValue: '2' }]
        }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `width` for your `radiogroup` and perhaps the `labelWidth`.

[image]

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2g37

[labelWidth](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Radio.html#cfg-labelWidth) in the docs.

Comment: I am glad I could help @nicolasbilous , it would be awesome if you could mark the answer as a correct one using the checkmark, thanks